# Should I use parentheses when writing $\log$?

Tags: notation

Should I be using parentheses when using things like $\log$ in LaTeX, and when handwriting?

Should I use $\log x$ or $\log(x)$?

If it's just one value or variable, I can see getting away with not using parentheses, but suppose I have a function in there:

$$
    \log p(w|v) \; \text{or} \; \log( p(w|v) ) \; ?
$$

Same question applies to things like $\sin$, $\arctan$, $\ln$, etc.

Comment: I prefer $\log x$; $\log p(w\mid v)$ is also unambiguous. On the other hand, one certainly needs parentheses for $\log(x+5)$. The same goes for all the rest.

Comment: writing $ \log x $ in latex is actually faster but as @BrianM.Scott said On the other hand, one certainly needs parentheses for log(x+5). The same goes for all the rest.

Comment: If it causes no ambiguity, I apply Tufte's 'maximize data-ink ratio' rule. So, in the above case, I would use $\log x$. Your other example is unambiguous, so the parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: A rule of thumb for special function names (trig functions both hyperbolic and ordinary, $\log$, $\exp$, …) is that their precedence is between multiplication and addition; moreover, you should generally use parentheses only when required.  So $\cos{2x}$ or $\cos{(x+5)}$.

Comment: That being said, $\cos x^2$ is fairly ambiguous.

Comment: @mjqxxxx I noticed you used a space between $\cos$ and the adjacent parentheses: $\cos \, (x+5)$. Do you always use this space for function-like operators (what's the rule (of thumb))? $\cos x^2$, hmm, due to PEMDAS, I'd say it's unambiguous: $\cos x^2 = \cos \, (x^2)$ The **other** thing is: $\cos^2 x = (\cos x)^2$

Answer (score 7):

If $f$ was a function and $x$ its argument: who in the mathematician's world would write $f\,x$ instead of $f(x)$? So the question really is: “What is the reason to omit the argument's brackets in some cases?”  (And how to remember these exceptions?  It's sort of remembering the list of all irregular verbs.) Besides of overcame  traditional unprogressive  reasons every teacher among us will agree that maximizing the data-ink ratio will as well minimize the readability, hence the grasping of what is written.

In case you're a teacher you should *always* put brackets around a function's argument, just for the sake of consistency.  In case you're not: correct your habit to avoid ambiguous expressions: Don't spare (digital) ink, write out your thoughts  as clearly as possible!

Comment: Actually, $fx$ (but not $f \ x$) is often used in various settings. Linear algebra and formal logic, for example.

Comment: In the context of Linear Algebra you omit a “\cdot” because if $A$ is a linear map we define $A(p):=A\cdot p$. About $f\,x$ and $fx$ consider the difference between $\cos x$ and $\mathrm{cos}x$.

Comment: As I understand it, $\log$ and $\sin$ etc, are /function-like operators/, as Larry Wall would call them, no doubt. I can see why they're treated differently, but for formal reasons, I asked this question.

Comment: To make things clearer: let $L\colon V\to W$ a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces and $p\in V$.  The image of $p$ under $L$ is $L(p)$. As we know $L$ can be represented by a matrix $A$ in the sense that $L(p)=Ap$.

Answer (score 1):

I treat $\log$ similarly to the trigonometric functions, so I would write $\sin x$ but I would write $\sin(x+k\pi)$ when the expression would be ambiguous without the parentheses.

So similarly, $\log x$, $\log f(x)$ and $\log\dfrac{1-x}{x}$ but $\log (1-x)$ and $\log(f(x)+g(x))$.

Comment: I kinda see it the same way, but I asked for formal reasons. Also, since things like $\log$ and $\sin$ are more like function-like operators, should there be a space between the function/operator and the argument in parentheses? $\log \, (a+b)$ or $\log(a+b)$ There has to be a space between the function and the argument if there are no parentheses for obvious reasons...

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/212201/88378

If it's not ambiguous, omitting parentheses can help readability.

$\log$ and $\sin$ are different from $f$ and $g$. The latter could denote a scalar for example, and putting $()$ after them makes it clear that they're functions. $\log$, $\sin$, etc are universally accepted to denote specific functions, so parentheses aren't necessary to clarify that.