# Which notation is better (more common) in math?

Tags: notation

Which one is better?

$$\arccos^2x^2\quad\quad \text{or}\quad\quad(\arccos x^2)^2$$

Are both notations acceptable?

Comment: A matter of taste. I prefer the more compact first version.

Comment: Both are fine. I often encounter the first one.

Comment: If I used the first version, I'd put parens around the x^2, for style reasons.

Comment: Ok, I got it. thank you guys!

Comment: I use both. I prefer the first, but sometimes there is a risk of confusing it with double derivative (which should be either $\arccos''$ or $\arccos^{(2)}$), or function composition. Parens around $x^2$ could also be used in both.

Comment: I remember the first term being used much often in my books

Comment: It's unfortunate that many people still use the first notation, it is awful. There are too many possible confusions as Jean-Claude pointed out. The second notation is much better.

Comment: Make life simpler using brackets of parentheses.

Comment: I also would use $\arccos^2(x^2)$, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544360/should-i-use-parentheses-when-writing-log/544563#544563

Answer (score 2):

Is $\arccos^2x$

- the inverse function of $\cos^2x$?
- the arccosine squared?

The first notation is therefore ambiguous. I always write $\cos^{-1}$ to mean $\arccos$, and so I would write the given expression as
$$(\cos^{-1}x^2)^2$$

Comment: Contemporary schools deprecate $\cos^{-1}$ as being ambiguous and imprecise. It is a multifunction with an unspecified principal branch. OTOH $\arccos$ is precisely and conventionally defined to mean "the branch of $\cos^{-1}$ whose image set is $\{x \in \mathbb R: 0 \le x \le \pi\}$".

Comment: @PrimeMover If $\log$ is also multivalued, why isn't it deprecated?

Comment: Why not ask that as a question on MSE?