# Is it clear enough if I remove -external-parentheses in $\sin ( (x-y)\pi )\; \cos ( (x+y)(a-\pi )) $?

Tags: notation

I have this expression
$$\sin ( (x-y)\pi )\; \cos ( (x+y)(a-\pi )) \qquad (1)$$

Is it clear if I omit those external parentheses and write it like this?
$$\sin  (x-y)\pi  \;\cos  (x+y)(a-\pi ). \qquad (2) $$

In general, which one is preferred?

Comment: I would prefer $(1)$ in both cases

Comment: It looks like $\sin{x-y}$ is being multiplied by $\pi$ which is not what is intended from the first form.

Comment: You might try $$\sin\bigl((x-y)\pi\bigr)\cdot \cos\bigl((x+y)(a-\pi)\bigr). \qquad (3)$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544360/should-i-use-parentheses-when-writing-log/544563#544563

Answer (score 3):

If the $\sin$ or $\cos$ function has only $1$ variable as an input then in many cases people just don't use the parentheses.

You might have seen $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ etc.

But in the example you have given, people will actually prefer the parentheses.

Because not only there are $2$ variables but a product going on.

If you write $\sin(x-y)\pi\cos(x+y)(a-\pi)$

Then people might confuse, are you trying to say $\sin((x-y)\pi)$ or $\pi\sin(x-y)$ which are obviously not equal in general.

Where writing $\sin((x-y)\pi)$ clearly says what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a nice way to avoid confusion is writing $\sin(xy)$ instead of $\sin(x)(y)$ which may easily with confused with the product of the functions $\sin x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, the second form is not clear at all, also as F. Ahmad Mala said, writing $\sin{x}y$ is not a good idea, adding to what he said, if you don't want pharanteses for some reason it is better to write it as $y.\sin{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first version. In fact, I would insist on it. As a general rule, I enter expressions in a form that would be correctly interpreted by mathematics software or as a line of computer code. Your second version would fail that test. I may appear to be taking directions from our machines, but it is important to avoid ambiguous expressions.

I notice that I now have parentheses around the argument of a trigonometric expression (e.g., sin(50°), not sin 50°) even in my had-written work. I do not believe I wrote that way 50 years ago, but I cannot even remember.